# How to use Fourier-Mellin transform for pattern matching?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, pattern-matching, fft, cross-correlation

I'm trying to use Fourier-Mellin transform to solve rotation, scale and translation invariant
pattern matching problem. But I'm stuck at how should I get image descriptors and how should I compare them (distance measure), what should I do after getting FMT images? I tried to calculate cross-correlation between them, but that's clearly not a good idea and doesn't yield any results.

Comment: To measure something you need to know what you want to measure. There are many measurements you can take using FFT, for instance read the technical report "Image Alignment and Stitching: A Tutorial" by R. Szeliski, 2004, to get some of the possible ways to use the frequency domain for the task.

Comment: I'm trying to use Fourier-Mellin transform to detect pattern in image. How do I compare these images thet I get after F-M transform?

Comment: You need descriptors that are obtained from the FMT. For instance, it seems like you are interested in similarity descriptors that are invariant to scale, rotation and translation. I'm aware that Derrode and Gorbel worked on this subject, and you should check their paper "Robust and efficient Fourier-Mellin transform approximations for gray-level image reconstruction and complete invariant description".

Comment: But can't I just directly compare two images after FMT? The algorithm for pattern-matching is not very clear from this paper, is it available in more simplified form?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to directly compare raw values even in spatial domain, let alone frequency domain.

Comment: Cross-correlation does make sense in spatial domain if perfectly aligned images are compared. But have no idea what to do with FMT.

Comment: If you have perfectly aligned images of exactly same dimensions, scaling, etc, then you aren't solving any problem.

Comment: Typical steps for rotation and translation invariance, including the calculation of FMT: http://pastebin.com/ZwPRFHLP, with example implementation at http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19731-fourier-mellin-image-registration

Comment: See this [paper](http://www.opticsinfobase.org/josaa/abstract.cfm?id=2371)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really helped! Is it correct that peak of phase correlation can be used as a distance measure between images?